# Umbraco 8, Can't Authorize Upgrade

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco8

This is driving me nuts. I did a fresh install of Umbraco 8.15 and now I'm trying to connect to my 7.15.7 database to do the upgrade, except I can't login to authorize the upgrade! I can literally see that the passwords are exactly the same hash in both databases. I've tried logging in with the username and email address but neither work. And yes, membership providers are using legacyEncoding = true and all other settings match.

Does anyone have a clue? This has stopped my migration to v8 dead in the water and there's nothing I see that should be preventing a login.

Really need help, I'm sure someone else ran into this problem?

Comment: Could you please show some pictures of your Web.config-files?

Comment: Check if it expects username or email.

Answer (score 0):

I saw [this "Login fails when trying to upgrade"](https://our.umbraco.com/forum/umbraco-8/98211-login-fails-when-trying-to-upgrade#comment-98211) problem and [here is how I fixed this problem](https://our.umbraco.com/forum/umbraco-8/98211-login-fails-when-trying-to-upgrade#comment-321990) at the time.

I also [created a blog for my Umbraco upgrade experience from v7 to v8](https://nurhak-kaya.blogspot.com/2020/07/umbraco-v8-upgrade-from-v7-developer.html) which might help you with some of the upgrade problems that you have seen/might see.

Answer (score 0):

It's because Umbraco 8 expects 10 letters for your password and Umbraco 7 expects 8, normally.

Before you start your Umbraco 8 site you should first copy the Membership settings from your Umbraco 7 Web.config to your Umbraco 8 Web.config.

This is also in the documentation:[image: Web.config Settings]

Answer (score 0):

The way passwords are encrypted changed in the update path.  In 8 you will get a new way.  in 7 you get the legacy way.  When you upgrade you will need to mess around in the web.config to make sure it works in legacy encryption mode

Basically, you will need to enable `uselegacy` on the membership provider line.  More info [here](https://www.jondjones.com/learn-umbraco-cms/umbraco-8-tutorials/upgrading-to-umbraco-8/developers-experience-of-upgrading-to-umbraco-v8/)